# How to get C# to initialize geckodriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, c#, geckodriver

I cannot find any implementations to get geckodriver to run my tests on FF for my C# solution, so I am reaching out to see what solutions you guys might have.

I have tried these two:

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                    service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
                    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```

This fails with the message *"The type or namespace name 'FirefoxDriverService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"*

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
                    var _driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

This fails the test claiming that it is unable to initialize the firefoxdriver.

> FF version #:49.0.2
>
> GeckoDriver version #: 0.11.1

Comment: Probably not the best solution but I couldn't get this to work with  the latest version of selenium.  I rolled back to a previous version of Selenium.Webdriver and Selenium.Support (2.53.1).  Now everything works with a simple "var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
"

Comment: That seems to be a solid workaround, but I am still curious if we can use the new development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, by updating to the latest version of Webdriver and Webdriver.support my first method of:

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                    service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
                    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```

Worked without issue.

Comment: Where did you place your geckodriver.exe file? Not specified in above code.

Comment: @zishanpaya I placed it into my C:\ drive in a folder I call selenium, you can see the reference to the location in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Specifying the geckodriver.exe path when creating the driver service solved the problem for me.

So assuming your geckodriver.exe is located in "C:\Selenium\geckodriver.exe", you could also write:

```
// Notice the path argument here
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Selenium");
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```